# Django Model Class Missing in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

For  some reason, the classes `archive` and `album` show all of their fields in the django admin panel, but `image` isn't showing an `album` field when I go to add an image to the image panel. If I open a shell, it shows that `album` is a subset of `image`, it just isn't showing up in the `image`'s admin interface (but it does through the CLI). Why?

```
class archive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    archivedata = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Documentation for album/image.archivedata methodology is put here")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class tag(models.Model):
    archive = models.ForeignKey(archive)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class album(models.Model):
    archive = models.ForeignKey(archive)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, blank=True, help_text="Searchable Keywords")
    archivedata = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Data specific to particular archiving methods or processes can be stored here")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class image(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(album)
    archive = models.ForeignKey(archive)
    imagefile = models.ImageField(upload_to='ns/') #image.width/height
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, help_text="Descriptive image title")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, blank=True, help_text="Searchable Keywords")
```

Update: Including my admin.py per request:

```
from django.db.models import get_models, get_app
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered

def autoregister(*app_list):
    for app_name in app_list:
        app_models = get_app(app_name)
        for model in get_models(app_models):
            try:
                admin.site.register(model)
            except AlreadyRegistered:
                pass

autoregister('appname')
```

Comment: What does your admin.py look like?

Comment: I updated my question to include admin.py for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any problem do you have some extra code in admin? Some code that overrides the `album field` ?

[image: Photo]

Comment: You're right. My database just exploded. Might take me a while to recover back to this point, thanks for y'all's patience. I'll report back soon.

Comment: Fixed. It was either MyImage or resetting the whole database. I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Your `admin.py` file should typically look like this.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(archive)
admin.site.register(album)
admin.site.register(image)
```

Based on your admin.py I would do this.

```
autoregister('archive', 'album', 'image')
```

That said a few pointers - Your admin.py is a bit overly complicated and not needed when 3 lines will suffice.  Additionally you should be naming your models in uppercase (Archive, Album, Image)

Comment: There are 14+ tables in the actual models.py- I stripped it down for simplicity. Nevertheless, I tried just doing a straight `admin.site.register` for each model and converting all of them to Uppercase syntax to keep things pythonic, but this did not work.

Comment: I know that if I delete archive from my `image` class, django is using it as some sort of key identifyer and throws an error when I go to make a new image in the admin web ui, if that's helpful to someone.

Comment: Works. I started over with mysql, and renamed to MyImage, but I suspect I needed to wipe the database to get it working. Thank you for the help though- I gave you as many points as I could for your time!